# La fonction de « que » et « qui »

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe

En faisant l'analyse de cette phrase :

> Un spéléologue est un homme **qui** explore les cavernes et les grottes
>   souterraines.

je me demandais quelle serait la fonction de *qui* ? Est-ce qu’il suffit de dire que c’est une conjonction ?

Également, ici :

> Il faut **que** tu me le dises.

Quelle est la fonction de *que* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

« Qui » est sujet du verbe « explorer ». C'est un pronom relatif ; il peut avoir deux fonctions : sujet, comme dans la présente phrase, ou bien COI.

Lorsqu'il est complément d'objet indirect il est précédé par « à » ou « de » ;

- L'élève **à qui** il a pris le cahier est revenu. (COI)
- La personne **de qui** elle parle est manquante. (COI)

Pour le mot « que » c'est différent ; c'est une conjonction de subordination et ces mots, comme les prépositions n'ont pas de fonction dans une proposition ; elles ont une fonction dans la phrase et c'est celle d'« introduire une proposition subordonnée ». La fonction de « que » est donc d'introduire la proposition subordonnée « tu me le dise ».

Voici l'essentiel, avec lequel devenir familier aussitôt que possible pour mieux comprendre les conjonctions de subordination ; c'est une copie de ce que l'on trouve sur le [site reverso](http://grammaire.reverso.net/1_1_30_La_conjonction_de_subordination.shtml) ;

> La conjonction de subordination est un mot invariable qui sert à introduire une proposition subordonnée.
>
> - Ses parents sont très fiers qu'il ait réussi le concours (La conjonction qu' introduit la proposition il ait réussi).
>
> Les conjonctions à proprement parler sont : **que, comme, lorsque, puisque, quand, quoique et si**.
>   Il existe par ailleurs de nombreuses locutions conjonctives : avant que, parce que, au cas où…
>
> Tout comme la préposition, la conjonction de subordination fait partie des mots qui n'ont pas de fonction grammaticale au sein de la phrase : **elle n'est complément d'aucun autre terme**. Elle sert à marquer le lien de dépendance entre la proposition qu'elle introduit et le terme auquel se rattache ce mot.
>
> - Il passera vous voir quand il sera revenu (dans cette phrase, seule la conjonction « quand » n'a pas de fonction. Elle marque le lien de dépendance entre le verbe « passer » et la proposition. Les autres mots ont tous une fonction par rapport à un autre terme de la phrase : « il » est le sujet du verbe passera, « vous » est complément du verbe « voir », etc.).

Comment: OK, dans : « Il faut que tu me le dises. » *que* est conjonction de subordination. Mais *que* peut être COD aussi. Ex. « C'est la robe que j'ai achetée hier. » Corrigez-moi, svp.

Comment: @lmc C'est exact.

Answer (score 1):

Fonctions de « que », « qu' » :

A/

> J'ai reçu un cadeau que je trouve très beau.

« Que » : pronom relatif. Il introduit une proposition subordonnée relative. « Que » représente l'antécédent qui se trouve dans la proposition principale.

B/

> Je pense que tu devrais relire cet exercice.

« Que » : conjonction de subordination. Il introduit une proposition subordonnée conjonctive. « Que » ne représente aucun autre mot.

C/

> Que manges-tu ce soir ?

« Que » : pronom interrogatif.

D/

> Que tu es belle !

« Que » : adverbe exclamatif.

> (Votre phrase) Il faut que tu me le dises.
>   « Que » : conjonction de subordination (Catégorie B).

https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-43220.php

http://blog.ac-versailles.fr/chemin/index.php/post/10/01/2016/Les-diff%C3%A9rentes-natures-de-que.

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que

---

Fonctions de « qui » (une seule orthographe !) :

A/ Pronom relatif des deux nombres, masculin ou féminin, désignant une personne ou une chose.

> Celui-là est trop vieux. Je veux un mouton qui vive longtemps. (Le Petit Prince, Antoine de Saint-Exupéry)

B/ Pronom interrogatif singulier désignant une personne.

> Qui fait le bruit ?  Qui attends-tu dans ce relais.

« Qui » est un prénom relatif dans votre exemple.

https://www.littre.org/definition/qui

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/qui

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaire_fran%C3%A7aise

Comment: Mais ce sont les espèces de mots, n'est-ce pas ? Ce ne sont pas les fonctions dans la phrase...